# avr-gcc atmega164pa error port undeclared

Tags: avr, avr-gcc, atmega, atmel

When compiling the following code:

```
#define F_CPU 1000000UL

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

int main(void) {

 DDRC = 255;

 while(1){

 PORTC=255;
 _delay_ms(200);

 PORTC=0;
 _delay_ms(200);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

for ATMega16 is fine:

```
avr-gcc -w -Os -DF_CPU=1000000UL -mmcu=atmega16 -c -o main.o main.c
```

However, for ATMega164PA, I get these errors:

```
avr-gcc -w -Os -DF_CPU=1000000UL -mmcu=atmega164pa -c -o main.o main.c
```

> error: `DDRC` undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> DDRC=255;
>
> ^
>
> error: `PORTC` undeclared (first use in this function)
>
> PORTC=255;
>
> ^

It is even fine with `atmega164p` but not `atmega164pa`

Comment: Looks purely like an avr-libc issue (in my copy, the m164pa is different from the other 164s, but does declare these ports). Check that yours is up to date, and if it still fails, report the bug to http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/ - or just use the working headers, Atmel doesn't even list a difference between A and PA models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue seems due to the fact that inside the file `io.h` there's no specific file inclusion for the MCU type `__AVR_ATmega164PA__`; there're only: `__AVR_ATmega164P__` and `__AVR_ATmega164A__` . I think the code for 164PA has to be compiled as 164P.

This is part of the code inside the file `io.h`

```
#elif defined (__AVR_ATmega163__)
#  include <avr/iom163.h>
//------------------------------------------------------------ To note
#elif defined (__AVR_ATmega164P__) || defined (__AVR_ATmega164A__)
#  include <avr/iom164.h>
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
#elif defined (__AVR_ATmega165__) || defined (__AVR_ATmega165A__)
#  include <avr/iom165.h>
```

If you see the compiler output, you might note more warnings:

```
In file included from avr164.c:3:0:
--------------------------------------------> To note
    /usr/lib/avr/include/avr/io.h:428:6: warning: #warning "device type not defined" [-Wcpp]
     #    warning "device type not defined"
          ^
To note <---------------------------------------------
avr164.c: In function ‘main’:
avr164.c:8:1: error: ‘DDRC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 DDRC = 255;
 ^
avr164.c:8:1: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
avr164.c:28:1: error: ‘PORTC’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 PORTC=255;
 ^
```

The first warning: `io.h:428:6: warning: #warning "device type not defined"` indicates you that the preprocessor has parsed the `io.h` file till the line that emits the warning.

In the following lines of the file `io.h` you may see where the warning is emitted.

```
    #elif defined (__AVR_M3000__)
    #  include <avr/iom3000.h>
    #else // <<<---------------------- To note!
// To note -------------------------------
    #  if !defined(__COMPILING_AVR_LIBC__)
    #    warning "device type not defined"
    #  endif
// To note -------------------------------
    #endif
```

The emitted warning indicates you that probably there're no libraries for the specified target (and "fortunately" for my debugging purpose indicates also the end of the section of interest).

If you try to compile the SW without managing `PORTC` and `DDRC` (commenting their use), you should have a result like this:

```
In file included from avr164.c:3:0:
/usr/lib/avr/include/avr/io.h:428:6: warning: #warning "device type not defined" [-Wcpp]
 #    warning "device type not defined"
      ^
---------------------------> Note
    /usr/lib/gcc/avr/4.8.2/../../../avr/bin/ld: cannot find crtm164pa.o: No such file or directory
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Note <---------------------------
```

The result indicates you there isn't a crtm164pa.o file in the linker environment. (And this is another problem!)

I've used: avr-gcc (GCC) 4.8.2